# Floating child window in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I want to create floating child window in .NET 3.0 WPF application.
What I'm doing is:

```
sideWindow = new SideWindow(this);
sideWindow.Left = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width -    sideWindow.Width;
sideWindow.Top = 125;
sideWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
sideWindow.Owner = this;
sideWindow.Show();
```

This is running fine except one customer. According to trace messages the window is created, but the client doesn't see it!

Any idea about similar problems?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the WPF native:

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth
```

I usually use SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth which works better with dual monitors.

Comment: I dump positions, height and width of the window and they are correct. If I try to find child window using Snoop, there is no such window in objects tree. 
But I can't find it on computer displaying the window too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this works at all: `sideWindow.Width` should be NaN (not a number) when you check it, because the layout passes haven't been performed at that point.

You need to call Measure/Arrange methods on sideWindow.